# Define HTML validation attributes with Laravel Blade syntax

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-4, jquery-validate, laravel-blade

I would like to combine the Laravel model binding properties with the easy [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), if that is possible.

I can't figure out how to add the 'required' attribute to the blade syntax.

Here is normal form syntax with the "required" attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="title" required>
```

Laravel Blade syntax

```
{{ Form:: text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`required` is a normal HTML input attribute. The only difference is that it doesn't have different values -- it's either present or it's not, which makes it the so-called boolean attribute.

Anyway, this should do the trick:

```
{{ Form:: text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
```

See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

Comment: thank you, that works great.  I didn't know it was an HTML attribute.

Comment: @retrograde, actually, it's an [HTML5 validation attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#HTML_Syntax_for_Constraint_Validation) and the jQuery Validate plugin will use HTML5 validation attributes in lieu of defining rules within the `.validate()` method.